# Generate .txt file with character increment t

Tags: php, increment, letter

I want to generate .txt file with following content

```
*.pdf.aa,*.pdf.ab,*.pdf.ac,*.pdf.ad............
*.pdf.ba,*.pdf.bb,*.pdf.bc,*.pdf.bd............
..............
..............
*.pdf.za,*.pdf.zb,*.pdf.zc,*.pdf.zd............
```

which is the best way to implement this ?How to increment a character like this

EDIT:
I tried below one

```
 for($i = 'aa'; $i <= 'z'; $i++) 
 { echo "$i ";}
```

Here its print upto yz only not printing za,zb ...

```
 aa ab ac.......... yu yv yw yx yy yz
```

Comment: You can increment a char variable, `$var = 'a'; echo ++$var;` will output `b`

Comment: `$i<'aaa'` instead of `$i <= 'z'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can incerement characters but you can do it with range()

```
$letters = range('a', 'z');

foreach($letters as $l) {
   foreach($letters as $l2) {
     echo $l.$l2.PHP_EOL;
   }
}
```

[Working fiddle](http://ideone.com/xcQO0s)

The other option based on @gbestard suggestion

```
for($a = 'aa' ; $a <= 'zz' && strlen($a) < 3 ; ++$a) {
  echo $a.PHP_EOL;
}
```

[Fiddle for second option](http://ideone.com/DVsKp0)

Comment: Actually, you CAN increment strings http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

Answer (score 0):

Change your for to:

```
for ($i = 'aa'; strlen($i) <= 2; $i++) {
    echo $i;
}
```

for some reason neither `$i <= 'zz'` or `$i < 'aaa'` works, so just check the length of the string.